# Resize exfat Hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, exfat

Is it still impossible to to resize, shrink or extend exfat partitions ? I cant find a way to do it, neither in windows nor with partitioning software. Any ideas other than formatting the partition to use a different file system ? I do not want to lose my data and do not have enough space for backup.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  You need to backup before you attempt ANY solution.

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: It sounds like its still not possible to extend exfat partitions based on my breif amount of research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrink exFAT partition](http://superuser.com/questions/393132/shrink-exfat-partition)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Disk Management can't resize exFAT partition, but you can use software to resize partition. if you have a computer running Windows, you can install [PartitionGuru Free](http://www.eassos.com/partitionguru-free.php) and then resize, shrink, split or extend partition. This tool doesn't support merge partitions. But the resizing thing works well, as the process doesn't cause data loss.